# Reiniciar servicio al generar excepcion

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un servicio que recibe eventos por TCP corriendo, el problema es que al ocurrir una excepción se me bloquea la aplicación, lo que quiero es que al ocurrir esta excepción se me reinicie el servicio.

```
using System;
using Logic;

namespace TestsConsole
{
  class Program
  {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Servicio Iniciado");
        ServicioBll servicioBll = new ServicioBll();

        servicioBll.Start();
        Console.Read();
        servicioBll.Stop();
    }
  }
}
```

Esta es la imagen de la excepción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: supongo que eso no es el codigo que lanza el error.. debe haber mucho mas.. y tu programa deberia tener un control de fallos para evitar eso... en general se usan controles keep alive para algo asi...

Comment: si amigo, el que lanza el error es en el manejo del socket, pero no hay forma de que cuando se bloquee el servicio se reinicie automaticamente

Comment: y el resto del codigo????

Comment: es un poco grande... son varias clases, lo pongo todo

Comment: mira [mcve].. debes poner la parte de codigo relevante

Comment: mete el codigo en una funcion, luego create en un try{} catch(), ese try{} chatch() lo metes en un while(funciona) { try{ funcion();funciona=true;} catch(exception ex) {funciona=false}}

Comment: Por cierto, el servicio en sus propiedades tienes la opcion de mandarlo restart on failure

Comment: Pero eso no es un servicio, no al menos un servicio de windows, es una aplicacion de consola

Comment: Veelicus, como se configura la opcion de restart on failure al servicio??

Answer (score 0):

Podrias controlar el `Exception` y hacer que vuelva a iniciar, algo como ser

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{

    do
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Servicio Iniciado");
            ServicioBll servicioBll = new ServicioBll();

            servicioBll.Start();
            Console.Read();
            servicioBll.Stop();
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }while(true)
}
```

como veras si hay un fallo vuelve al inicio del `do..while`, pero si se presiona una tecla ejecuta el `break` entonces termina